# Calendar.SelectedDate not working for dates in the future

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have some odd behaviour on my website. I have an ASP Calendar called UDExpiryCalendar that gets its values on page load. I read in a `DateTime` from the User's record and populate the `UDExpiryCalendar.VisibleDate` and `UDExpiryCalendar.SelectedDate` then `UDExpiryCalendar.DataBind();`

I get these results:

- The date is in the past - The correct month is displayed, the correct year is displayed and the correct date is selected.
- The date is in this month - The correct month is displayed, the correct year is displayed, the current day is greyed and the correct date is selected (even if a few days in the future).
- The date is in the future - The correct month is displayed, the correct year is displayed but the selected date is NOT selected

Any ideas?

C#

```
var userID = Request.QueryString["ID"];

string getUserInfo = "select * from UserList where Id =" + userID;
SqlCommand getUserInfocmd = new SqlCommand(getUserInfo, con);
getUserInfocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader sqlDR = getUserInfocmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(sqlDR);
sqlDR.Close();

DateTime oldExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][6]);

UDExpiryCalendar.VisibleDate = oldExpiryDate;
UDExpiryCalendar.SelectedDate = oldExpiryDate;
UDExpiryCalendar.DataBind();
```

ASP

```
<asp:Calendar ID="UDExpiryCalendar" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px">
    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
    <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
</asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: please post all your relevant code

Comment: @duerzd696 Hi, I've added more of my code

Comment: Did you try setting the mindate property also?   Like : UDExpiryCalendar.MinDate = oldExpiryDate; ;UDExpiryCalendar.VisibleDate = oldExpiryDate; 
        UDExpiryCalendar.SelectedDate = oldExpiryDate;
        UDExpiryCalendar.DataBind();

Comment: @duerzd696 There is no MinDate property or anything similar I can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your date has time components within it.  I tested this and it worked(in Page_Load):

```
 Calendar1.SelectionMode = CalendarSelectionMode.Day;
 Calendar1.TodaysDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
 Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear();
 Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2).Date;
 Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2).Date;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! I've been testing with 7 users and as luck would have it, the 2 "in the past" that worked have a 00:00:00 time and the rest don't. I've corrected my code and it is all working.

Comment: Just going through my other code and I have a page that does work as intended and here I also set the UMExpiryCalendar.TodaysDate value. This makes the others work with a time also